# Install python CV2 on spark cluster(data bricks)

Tags: python, opencv, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

i want to install pythons library CV2 on a spark cluster using databricks community edition and i'm going to:
workspace-> create -> library , as the normal procedure and then selecting python in the Language combobox, but in the "PyPi Package" textbox , i tried "cv2" and "opencv" and had no luck. Does anybody has tried this? Do you know if cv2 can be installed on the cluster through this method? and if so, which name should be used in the texbox?

Answer (score 1):

Try to download `numpy` first followed by `opencv-python` it will work.

Steps:

1. Navigate to Install Library-->Select PyPI----->In Package--->numpy
   (after installation completes, proceed to step 2)
2. Navigate to Install Library-->Select PyPI----->In Package--->opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

The PyPi package you want is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python -- so just put opencv-python in the textbox and install.